# How do I list all site languages in ektron?

Tags: ektron

I find it really hard to find accurate documentation on many tasks related to ektron. So here I am, asking a relatively simple question. How do i get, programatically, a list of all site languages?

I find a couple server controls in the documentation, some articles, but not how got to get from there to a simple api call that gets me the list of languages (pseudocode).

List SomeEktronManager.GetAllLanguages();

Here is some resources that are not quite I need. 
http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/EDR/Web/EDR.htm#Server_Controls/Language/LanguageSelect.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, at the end I think I got it. There seems to be an ektron API and and Ektron framework API and two server side controls that can either render a dropdown list of all languages or set the sites language (one of the server side controls is called "LanguageAPI"). 
What i needeed was just to get a list of languages active for the site. So here it is:

```
Ektron.Cms.API.Site s = new Ektron.Cms.API.Site();
var languages = s.GetAllActiveLanguages();
```

Now not sure how this instance of "site" works and what happens in a multi-site setup, but thats an ektron issue for another day.